How to increase gap between rows?
I am using the React Native calendar. Everything is done except 2 things.

I want to add a gap between rows of dates so my custom background rectangular shape will have extra space.

I want to add a gradient of 2 colors to my custom background rectangular shape in react native calendar instead of only one color.



Gradient colors:
    colors: ['#FFC011', '#FB3B16'],  
    start: {x: 0, y: 0},  
    end: {x: 1, y: 0},  

        <Calendar
          style={{
            backgroundColor: theme.background,
            gap: 20,
          }}
          renderArrow={(direction = 'right') =>
            direction == 'right' ? <CalendarArrow /> : <LeftArrow />
          }
          markingType="custom"
          theme={{
            backgroundColor: theme.background,
            calendarBackground: theme.background,
            textSectionTitleColor: theme.primaryText,
            selectedDayTextColor: theme.primaryText,
            todayTextColor: theme.primaryText,
            dayTextColor: theme.primaryText,
            textDisabledColor: theme.primaryText,
            textMonthFontColor: theme.primaryText,
            textMonthFontSize: 14,
            textMonthFontWeight: '500',
            textDayFontSize: 12,
            textDayFontWeight: '400',
          }}
          onDayPress={day => {
            setSelected(day.dateString);
          }}
          markedDates={{
            [selected]: {
              selected: true,
              disableTouchEvent: true,
              customStyles: {
                container: {
                  backgroundColor: theme.highlight,
                  borderRadius: 8,
                  // margin: 5,
                  height: Height('6'),
                  width: 45,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignSelf: 'center',
                  bottom: 10,
                },
                text: {
                  color: theme.primaryText,
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  fontSize: 12,
                },
              },
            },
          }}
          enableSwipeMonths={true}
          renderHeader={(date: string | number | Date) => {
            const monthName = new Date(date).toLocaleString('default', {
              month: 'long',
            });
            return (
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: '500',
                  color: theme.primaryText,
                }}>
                {monthName}
              </Text>
            );
          }}
/>


You can define the way date rendered by overriding dayComponent. There you can write your custom view with gradient backgrounds, paddings or custom height or whatever you like. Documentation.
